# Dart files not visible in the Android Studio, after Android Studio and Flutter re-installation, for an old Flutter projects

Tags: android-studio, flutter, dart

Dart files not visible in the Android Studio, after Android Studio and Flutter re-installation, for an old Flutter project, but everything is fine if creating a new Flutter project. Flutter SDK path was provided in the old Flutter project because automatically it wasn't provided by Android Studio after re-installation.

[image][image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Maybe you have opened the android project in the studio. Look for files in your explorer. The structure is like the Flutter project is at the base level and there are android and ios folders inside it that contain the respective platform-specific applications. Add a screenshot of your hierarchy if you need further help.

Comment: Screenshots added :)

Comment: It's really strange. You have the correct flutter project open... Are you sure the dart files are still there? Can you look for them in the explorer?

Comment: They are not visible in there. It seems as they have gone :(

Comment: Strange 5 projects and all dart files were gone.

Comment: I am really unable to conclude anything :( You should probably report a bug if you think it happened because of the update and always store a backup of your project somewhere.

Comment: Thanks :) I have them In the GitHub :) just not the first time happens like this, so decide to ask, maybe somebody knows a quick fix.

Comment: @Laura can you check by just using Finder or File Explorer(Depending on the OS you're using) if they exist in your drive. If they do, check if Dart SDK is supported by the project and the content root for the project is selected.

Comment: If it is a flutter project then Android Studio should automatically recognize it as a flutter project if dart and flutter sdks are configured properly. In your case, I don't think the project is properly configured. Make sure you also have both Dart and Flutter Plugins for Android Studio

Comment: Something is really wrong because my projects don't have any more files : gitignore, metadata, packages, .iml, pubspec.lock, pubspec.ymal, and Readme.md

Comment: I have both Plugins, Dart and Flutter SDK's paths are provided. I am able to create new projects.